# Switching keyboard layout intercepts window focus & collapses fullscreen windows in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 22.04, fullscreen

Hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch keyboard layout seriously disrupts my workflow. Every time I switch the layout, text fields get unfocused and I have to select the field again to start typing. And it's just unusable in fullscreen mode, because the fullscreen window gets collapsed.

I suppose, it's some kind of bug, related to the keyboard layout-switching overlay (normally it appears after you hold <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for a second). It seems like it appears event if I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> very briefly and throws focus off the active windows.

What can I do about this? Isthere some config to disable this overlay altogether?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps change the shortcut key to Control+Space (or something you like) will only do the layout change. Now `Super` key bound to a window manipulation, imho.

Comment: Well, this is a default combination in many systems. Anyway, rebinding doesn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using this extension solved my problem: [Quick Lang Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/)

Comment: This is the best option for solving this issue and also removes the quite annoying delay of the language switcher!

Comment: OMG it really works. Faced the issue of unfocusing a whole window on input source change and didn't find anything else expect ur answer. Quick and productive solution

Comment: Great! I expected there to be some Gnome extension for that

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround but not a solution, unfortunately.
As [@Viktor mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1423914/618353), you can select your option in Tweaks (but excluding <kbd>Win</kbd> key in my experience), for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Also you need to disable shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in System Settings → *Keyboard* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* → *Typing*.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found is to change a setting in Tweaks: In the *Windows* section change the *Window Focus* to *Focus on Hover* or *Secondary-Click*.

It may be tricky at first, but you get used to it at no time.

Answer (score 0):

I use GNOME Tweak Tool (GNOME Tweaks in the Ubuntu Software now) as a workaround:

- *Keyboard & Mouse* in the left menu.
- *Additional Layout Options* button in the right part of the window.
- *Switching to another layout*.
- Select the combination you want. It will not show the overlay.

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool]

And in general I'm waiting for a solution too. It's very annoying and completely unusable with individual input source for each window. In this case language is switched only for the language switch overlay.